# remove duplicated set of columns in table

Tags: sql, mariadb, apriori

I created co-occurrence table as follows.

```
col1 col2 count
a    b    10
b    a    10
c    d    7
d    c    7
```

I want to keep co-occurrence rows without duplication like this.

```
col1 col2 count
a    b    10
c    d    7
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple method is:

```
select col1, col2, count
from t
where col1 < col2;
```

If you actually want to change the table, you can do:

```
delete t from t
    where col1 > col2;
```

This assumes that all pairs of columns are in the database.

Answer (score 0):

When inserting or selecting, do something like this instead of `col1, col2`:

```
LEAST(col1, col2), GREATEST(col1, col2)
```